# Duplicated Rows in Table View

Tags: ios, uitableview, uilabel

I know there're similar questions like this, but they don't work for me!

I'm having my rows duplicated, and the text of the UILabel gets bolder and bolder when user comes back to any tab with table views.

Here's the code of cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)
[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellClassName];

if (cell == nil) 
{
    NSArray *topLevelItems = [cellLoader instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil];
    cell = [topLevelItems objectAtIndex:0];
}

cell.subnavName.text = [array objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]];

UIImageView *background = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"subnavigation_off.png"]];

[cell setBackgroundView:background];

background = [[UIImageView alloc] 
              initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"subnavigation_on.png"]];

cell.selectedBackgroundView = background;
[background release];

return cell;
```

}
What can I do to avoid the text from the UILabel to be added again on my cells when user comes back to this tab from another one? I read something about use the tag, but I can't find the way to do it.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Soooooo classic mistake.

The problem (as quite always about TableView questions here) is that you don't use the reuse mechanism of the TableViewCells correctly.

You should try to dequeue (recycle) an existing cell, and if it does not return a cell (the tableview didn't manage to recycle an old -- already allocated but not used any more -- cell) then allocate it and configure every property that will be common to all your cells (label font, adding subviews, changing colors, etc).

Then, outside of the "if" -- so whether the cell is a newly allocated one or a cell that has been recycled (from a previously allocated but no more used cell), in all cases -- fill the cell with the specific content that depends on the indexPath (text, image, etc)

Read the Table View Programming Guide in Apple documentation, and search on StackOverflow too there are a lot of questions about TableViews that all have the same issue.

Comment: I changed it and it's still not working, can you please edit my code above? Thans in advance.

Comment: I don't see any edit/change in your code above. For exemples of how to implement this, search StackOverflow about `UITableView`, there are **loads and loads** of code samples about how to implement `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and this `if` branch, and I myself explained it multiple times around here.

Comment: Ok, I changed in my app code, not there. Just edited. Thanks :)

Comment: WTF?! Why all this useless code ? A for loop to find which value of `i` is equal to `indexPath.section` instead of just using `indexPath.section` directly ?! And you have leaks on the first image you assign in `background` variable too... And still "still now working" is not a diagnostic. Can't help w/o more details. Do put breakpoints in your code and debug it step by step (or NSLog it) it should be more clear for you.

Comment: WTF don't you modify my code so I'll learn how to do it the right way and I won't need to ask again? Thanks for your help. Sorry because I'm not so good programmer as you. I'm sure you weren't born knowing how to program.

Comment: I think you didn't understand the way SO works. SO is not the place for requests like making others write your code for you. I wasn't born knowning how to program, so I did loads of tutorials and read books. Did not ask others to write the code for me.

Comment: Yeah, I know you can't come here and say: Hey, please, make my app! But, I'm trying to solve this little issue and I can't, I try and doesn't solve my problem. So I ask. And I find people like you that only answer "how can you be so stupid and use that code". That's not help, I'm sure you don't want to be treated like this. Thanks for all.